# check if a private channel invite link is invalid/expired in telethon

Tags: telethon

When you try to access a private channel using expired link in telegram client you will get this message
[expired link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr83U.png)

is there a way to check if a channel invite link is invalid or expired without joining the channel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`checkChatInvite`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/check_chat_invite.html):

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.messages.CheckChatInviteRequest(
        hash='A4LmkR23G0IGxBE71zZfo1'
    ))
    print(result.stringify())
```